# How to receive data in a PySimpleGUI GUI?

Tags: python, flask, pysimplegui

I want to continuously display some data that I receive in a Flask Server in a GUI that I designed with PySimpleGUI. Currently my GUI and my Flask Server are two seperate projects, what would be the cleanest/best practise method to connect them?

Answer (score 0):

The way you "receive data" in PySimpleGUI will be inside the event loop.  Usually communicating with a GUI subsystem is through something like a queue.

Use a timeout values on your `window.Read(timeout=100)` call so that it doesn't completely block.  This will enable it to read the queue or make a function call or do whatever it has to do to get the data.